# How can I aggregate shortened O-D data geocodes along with its associated frequency data in R?

Tags: r, aggregate

I am a relatively new user with R but I have been having to teach myself the language on the fly in order to complete my research assignment for an internship.

I am working with origin-destination census data files. This data looks something a bit like this:

```
w_geocode       h_geocode S000 SA01 SA02 SA03 SE01 SE02 SE03 SI01 SI02 SI03

1  360010001001005 - 360010001001010 -  1    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0

2 360010001001005 - 360010001001011  -  1    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0

3 360010001001005 - 360010001001039  -  1    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0

4 360010001001005 - 360010014001009  -  1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0

5 360010001001005 - 360010015001007 -   1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0

6 360010001001005 - 360010019011001  -  1    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
```

There are about 5 million rows of data like this. Each one of these 15 digit numbers represent a very specific location. In order to make this data more relevant, I have managed to shorten these 15 digit codes to 11 digit codes using:

```
options(scipen=100)  #to avoid scientific notation

nyod=read.csv("ny_od_main_JT00_2010.csv")

x=nyod[,1]

y=nyod[,2]

z=nyod[,3]

tx=trunc(x/10000)

ty=trunc(y/10000)

nyodI=cbind(tx,ty,z)
```

After which I get something like this:

```
              tx          ty z
[1,] 36001000100 36001000100 1

[2,] 36001000100 36001000100 1

[3,] 36001000100 36001000100 1

[4,] 36001000100 36001001400 1

[5,] 36001000100 36001001500 1

[6,] 36001000100 36001001901 1
```

But now, as you can see, I have redundancies which I would like to aggregate. Ideally, for example, now I would like to see rows 1, 2, and 3 consolidated to one and z's sum equate to 3. But I would need this process to be done for all redundancies.

I hope my question is specific enough and makes sense to whomever may read it. Thanks for any help you may provide!

Comment: Can you format your question to make it more readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `base` packages, you just need to use `aggregate` function.

```
nyodI
##            tx          ty z
## 1 36001000100 36001000100 1
## 2 36001000100 36001000100 1
## 3 36001000100 36001000100 1
## 4 36001000100 36001001400 1
## 5 36001000100 36001001500 1
## 6 36001000100 36001001901 1

aggregate(z ~ tx + ty, data = nyodI, FUN = sum)
##            tx          ty z
## 1 36001000100 36001000100 3
## 2 36001000100 36001001400 1
## 3 36001000100 36001001500 1
## 4 36001000100 36001001901 1
```

Comment: @geektrader Fantastic! I have been scouring the web for days looking for a way to accomplish this one thing. I really appreciate your speedy reply to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your first part  of truncating data is very long , you can just do :

```
dat <- nyod[,1:3]
nyod[,1:2] <- trunc(nyod[,1:2]/1000)
```

For the rest , you can use as suggested `aggregate`, `ddply`.

Comment: Thank you for your help as well. I know I still have a lot to learn in R. I still don't even have the basics down.   @agstudy

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
library(plyr) 
df <– ddply(nyodI, .(tx, ty), summarise, z.sum=sum(z))
```